# How to Copy some rows into same table with concated variable primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I am trying to copy some rows into same table. Just want to update a column which is primary key. How can I do that By an Incremental variable.

```
USE [Target Database] 
GO  
BEGIN
DECLARE @x INT=0
SET @x=@x+1
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Target_Table] ([Primary_Key],[Col1],[Col2])  
SELECT CONCAT('50487' ,FORMAT( @x ,'000') ) as [Primary_Key],[Col1],[Col2]
   FROM [dbo].[Target_Table]
   WHERE [dbo].[Target_Table].col1=54706
END
```

Sample Existing Data:

```
Primary_Key   Col1    Col2
50409001      54706   Test1
.
.
.
50409050      54706   Test2
```

I want to make this:

```
Primary_Key   Col1    Col2
50487001      54706   Test1
.
.
.
50487050      54706   Test2
```

Comment: update your question  add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled about what you mean.

This is pseudo-code, I presume, because it wouldn't work in T-SQL as written.  

Are there many rows with Col1 = 54706?

Is your Primary_Key a number stored as a string (varchar for example)?

In this code the new Primary_Key will always be '50487001' so this will work only if there is only one row with Col1 = 54706.

If you're trying ot do what I think you're trying to do then there are easier ways, but I'd need to really understand what you are trying to do so that I could answer your question.

Comment: I have updated my question. 
Yes there are many rows with col1=54706. primary key is 'INT' type. but I want to store it in this format, '50487***'. this three stars will be increased in each row like this...001,002,003....999. So the primary key will be like 50487001, 50487002,50487003....50487999

Comment: Do something like `insert into t select pk + val, col1, col2 from t where ...`

Comment: @jarlh not working

Comment: please share yor target table structure

Comment: @HasanFathi Same table is the target table. I want to replace existing data.

Comment: i want see your Primary_Key field structure. this the identity key?

Comment: @Faisal Nabil In one place you say you wish to copy and in another replace which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
drop table tmp;
go

create table tmp(id int primary key, col1 int, col2 int)
go
truncate table tmp
insert into tmp values (1,10,100),(2,20,2),(3,10,200);

insert into tmp 
select 4000 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) - 1 rn,col1,col2
from tmp
where col1 = 10

select * from tmp

id          col1        col2
----------- ----------- -----------
1           10          100
2           20          2
3           10          200
4000        10          100
4001        10          200

(5 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should help you:

```
DECLARE @myTableVariable table (idx int IDENTITY(50487001,1), [Col1] nvarchar(50), [Col2] nvarchar(50))
--The PrimaryKey number you need will automatically be genrated by identity column

INSERT INTO @myTableVariable(Col1, Col2)
SELECT [Col1],[Col2] FROM [dbo].[Target_Table] WHERE [dbo].[Target_Table].col1=54706

--IF [Target_Table] Primary_Key is IDNTITY, you neeed to set identy insert ON
--SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Target_Table] ON


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Target_Table] ([Primary_Key],[Col1],[Col2])  
SELECT idx, Col1, col2 FROM @myTableVariable

--SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Target_Table] OFF
```